# resizable Grid Row and Grid Item

Tags: apache-flex, resize, flex-mx

I have an `mx:Grid` component in my flex application. But I would like to resize it by clicking and dragging in the border. This component doesn't allow doing that. Does anybody know any custom component to do this?

I want to put a panel in each gridItem of this Grid component and resize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!
I have used a resizable custom component inside GridItem and now the gridItem sets its width and heigth same as custom component.